# I keep getting out of bounds on this array... why?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Question is the title basically....  Why does this program not like me:3   I Keep getting an "ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   double[] l1 = {1.2, 3.4, 1.2, 3.4, 1.1};
   double[] l2 = {1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6};

   isSorted(l1);
   isSorted(l2);

}
public static void isSorted(double[] l1){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

     if (l1[2]>l1[1])
         if(l1[3]>l1[2])
             if(l1[4]>l1[3])
                 if(l1[5]>l1[4])
                 System.out.println("True");
     else
                 System.out.println("False");
}
```

Is it because I pre-filled the array?

edit2: Ignore the scanner.

Edit 3:  Wow.  Okay.  Indexing starts at 0 and I am an idiot!

Thanks.  -_-

Comment: Indexing starts at 0. Use a for loop to check if it's sorted.

Comment: How would I use a for loop to check though?

Comment: You always need to check the next element (or prev in reverse order). Use a loop that goes from 0 to `length - 1`.

Comment: I'm having trouble using a for loop to compare index values.   So far I can't get the compiler to print anything.

Answer (score 1):

note this1

```
if(l1[5]>l1[4])
```

but you have only 5 values in `l1` array. but you access `l1[5]`

```
l1[0],l1[1],l1[2],l1[3],l1[4]
```

these are all five values, but you access `l1[5]`, so it raise the Exception.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in java are 0-base. It means that you can not access index 5 in your case.
If you use java it is also better to use some implementation of List's interface.

I just wonder how much time did you spend debuging your code. 
(In your case it would be enough just to print elements to realize that arrays are zero based.)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in java are done using 0 based counting. This means that the first element in the array is `l1[0]`. so therefore the line of code that uses `l1[5]` means your accessing an element that is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

The arrays index in Java and most languages starts from 0:

```
if ((l1[1]>l1[0]) && (l1[2]>l1[1]) && (l1[3]>l1[2]) && (l1[4]>l1[3]))
    System.out.println("True");
else
    System.out.println("False");
```